# How to change the return value 'TRUE' to '1' using the Count If Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a spreadsheet used for attendance, we wanted to record the times subjects attended we did this by assigning time slots numbers.

`A= 11:00 - 12:00`, `B=12:00 - 1:00` and so on.

I am trying to write a formula that gives me a `1`, if they have attended one or more times during a specific date range (The month of Jan).

I'm currently using this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(HO6:HV6,"*")>0
```

This is producing the correct response. I get `TRUE` If there attendance mark is within the date range and `FALSE` if there is no value in the range o cells. However I'd like to change the displayed text `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use double minus `--` after `=` equal sign of formula like below.

```
=--(COUNTIF(HO6:HV6,"*")>0)
```

Comment: The double minus are also called double unary or double negative as well. The other coercion routes are  `=(COUNTIF(HO6:HV6,"*")>0)*1`, `=(COUNTIF(HO6:HV6,"*")>0)+0` etc.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij in simple word do a math operation with result which will return a numeric value.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this formula has changed every TRUE and FALSE to a 1. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Bassface88 you are missing something. It can't happen. It will convert `TRUE` to `1` and `False` to `0`. Please double check your formula.

Comment: Very strange - I copied the formula and entered it into the cell and it worked, However when I copied it into the formula bar it returned all 1's. Thank you for your help Harun24HR.

Comment: @Bassface88 Ensure that Automatic calculation is selected, or else, force calculation by click on 'Calculate Sheet' (both options under formulas tab) https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kfof.png

Comment: @Bassface88 If you found the answer useful the consider [Accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.